# How can a js code take an input file using the terminal?

Tags: javascript, shell

So I need to use an input file in my terminal, and when I write the following `cat input.txt | node prog.js >result.txt`

My code is :

```
var fs = require('fs');
var str = fs.readFileSync('input.txt', 'utf8');

str.replace(/^\s*[\r\n]/gm,"").split(/\s+/).forEach(function (s) {
    return console.log(
    s === 'bob'
        ? 'boy'
        : s === 'alicia'
        ? 'girl'
        : s === 'cookie'
        ? 'dog'
        : 'unknown');
});
```

I need my code to take an input document regardless of the name the user may give it. What is the correct way to grab user input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Piping something into a Node script does require you to read from `process.stdin`, as @T.J.Crowder mentions.

Have a look at this article, which explains the idea, with a good example to follow:
https://blog.rapid7.com/2015/10/20/unleash-the-power-of-node-js-for-shell-scripting-part-1/
e.g.:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node 
const readInput = callback => {
  let input = '';
  process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');
  process.stdin.on('readable', () => {
      const chunk = process.stdin.read();
      if (chunk !== null) {
          input += chunk;
      }
  });
  process.stdin.on('end', () => callback(input));
}
readInput(console.log);
```

Answer (score 2):

if you pipe out a value to a node.js script you have to listen to the `readable` or `data` event listener available to the `process` object. Using the `data` event listener places the stream straight into flowing mode, whenever you use the `readable` event listener you have to force stdin to flowing mode using `process.stdin.read()`. To write to another command or to another script you have to use `process.stdout.write()`, it's a writeable stream.

**Flowing mode**

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

let chunks = "";

process.stdin.on("data", data => {
    // data is an instance of the Buffer object, we have to convert it to a string
    chunks += data.toString();
})

// the end event listener is triggered whenever there is no more data to read

process.stdin.on("end", () => {
    // pipe out the data to another command or write to a file
    process.stdout.write(chunks);
});
```

**Non Flowing mode**

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

process.stdin.on("readable", () => {
    const flowingMode = process.stdin.read();
    // flowingMode will become null, whenever there is no more data to read
    if ( flowingMode )
        chunks += flowingMode.toString();
})

process.stdin.on("end", () => {
    process.stdout.write(chunks);   
})
```

To prevent your self all this stress, you can do something like the below if there is non logic on the `readable` or `data` event handler

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

process.stdin.pipe(process.stdout);
```

if you want to do something whenever the `end` event listener is triggered you should do this

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

process.stdin.pipe(process.stdout, { end: false } );

process.stdin.on("end", () => /* logic */ );
```

when the `end` event listener is triggered execute your code

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

let chunk = "";

process.stdin.on("data", data => {
    chunk += data.toString();
});

process.stdin.on("end", () => {
    chunk.replace(/^\s*[\r\n]/gm,"").split(/\s+/).forEach(function (s) {
        process.stdout.write(
        s === 'bob'
        ? 'boy'
        : s === 'alicia'
           ? 'girl'
           : s === 'cookie'
               ? 'dog'
               : 'unknown');
    });
});

> cat input.txt | ./prog.js > result.txt
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer, but sorry I don't understand how can I mix  it with my code?

Comment: That is not the question you asked

Comment: I am so sorry my question was not clear, it's my fault. For me the goal it's to use the following command I put in my post, and I don't know how can I code in JS in order to use the command. Because we can change the name of the following input "input.txt", and I want a code which take  any file name enters in commade in the terminal

Comment: Thank you for your answer @0.sh

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking is "How do I read from standard input?" The answer is to use [`process.stdin`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_stdin), which is a [`Stream`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_stream).